# Deep Link handling in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, deep-linking, android-navigation

I am building a shop app. The user can share the product through message, email etc.
My Task is once the oter user who received the share link click on that link, my app should open and navigate to product detail page and using the product ID from URI to fetch the product.

I am using Firebase Dynamic links to generate short links.
When I click on the link lets say in Message App. My application would open in the Message app and not as separate App. I fixed this by changing my activity launch mode to

```
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

It was working only if my app wasnt started. But when the App was in background, clicking the link wouldnt do anything.

I am not sure how to implement my override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) func to handle the deeplink correctly.
Currently I found TEMP solution which is working, but im not sure if its the right way of doing it. My code for newIntent.

```
    class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    
    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    
    val pendingIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(applicationContext).run {
    addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent)
    getPendingIntent(
    0,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                )
            }
    pendingIntent.send()
        }
     }
```

my Manifest file:

```
  <activity android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name=".presentation.MainActivity" android:exported="true" android:theme="@style/Theme.B2CApp">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="*****.page.link" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

And this is how i navigate with deepLink

```
composable(
                    CategoryRoute.ProductDetail.route,
                    deepLinks = listOf(
                        navDeepLink {
                            uriPattern = "****.page.link/{$DEEP_LINK}"
                            action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
                        }
                    ),
                    arguments = listOf(
                        navArgument(PRODUCT_ID) {
                            type = NavType.StringType
                            defaultValue = ""
                        },
                        navArgument(DEEP_LINK) {
                            type = NavType.StringType
                            defaultValue = ""
                        }
                    )
                )
```

I tried to call havController to handle deep link from newIntent func, but I dont have access to navHostController in MainActivity file.

UPDATE: after @Watermelon suggestions:
My Manifest file didn't change.
My main activity now looks like this:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val newIntent by produceState(initialValue = null as Intent?) {
                val consumer = androidx.core.util.Consumer<Intent> {
                    this.value = it
                }
                addOnNewIntentListener(consumer)
                awaitDispose {
                    removeOnNewIntentListener(consumer)
                }
            }
            B2CTheme {
                MainScreen(newIntent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My MainScreen is:

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MainScreen(newIntent: Intent?) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
    val currentIntent = rememberUpdatedState(newValue = newIntent)

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        snapshotFlow { currentIntent.value }.filterNotNull()
            .map {
                /* do extra jobs*/
                println(it.dataString)
                it

            }
            .collect{
                navController.handleDeepLink(it)
            }
    }

    SideEffect {
        systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(
            color = LightColorScheme.surface,
            darkIcons = true
        )
    }

    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            B2CBottomBar(navController) {
                navController.navigate(it.route) {
                    launchSingleTop = true
                    popUpTo(it.route) {
                        inclusive = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ) {
        MainNavHost(
            navController = navController,
            Modifier.padding(top = it.calculateTopPadding()))
    }
}
```

Also, my initial solution has a bug.
When a user clicks on a link from outside, my app opens and shows the product correctly in my HomeTab. If I click back button, it takes me back to the root home tab. If I select any other tab from my bottom navigation and click on Home tab again, I still see the product that I got from the DeepLink.

Answer (score 4):

1. If you can access Acitivity directly.

```
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    DisposableEffect(navController) {
        val consumer = Consumer<Intent> {
            navController.handleDeepLink(it)
        }
        this@MainActivity.addOnNewIntentListener(consumer)
        onDispose {
            this@MainActivity.removeOnNewIntentListener(consumer)
        }
    }
```

2.Or if you want to decouple it some how.

```
class FeatureHostingActivity: ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val newIntent by produceState(initialValue = null as Intent?) {
                val consumer = androidx.core.util.Consumer<Intent> {
                    this.value = it
                }
                addOnNewIntentListener(consumer)
                awaitDispose {
                    removeOnNewIntentListener(consumer)
                }
            }
            FeatureApp(newIntent)
        }
    }

}
```

FeatureApp can handle intent like this

```
@Composable
fun FeatureApp(newIntent:Intent?) {
    
    val currentIntent = rememberUpdatedState(newValue = newIntent)
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        snapshotFlow { currentIntent.value }.filterNotNull()
            .map { 
                /* do extra jobs*/
                it
            }
            .collect{
                navController.handleDeepLink(it)
        }
    }
    /* your features */
}
```

If `handleDeepLink` is not working as you expected, consider adding IntentFlags in your intent-filter.

- [FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
- [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
- [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
- [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

or configure it and navigate to the destination on your own by calling `navigate` rather than `handleDeepLink`. But I don't recommend that way cause that will cause different behavior between launching new activity by deeplink vs updating existing activity using deeplink

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Can you please clarify where the option 2 code should go? I am new to Android development.

Comment: @DaveKababyan edit the answer with more detail

Comment: Does this solution mean that I have to have 2 activities in my Manifest file? similar to the solution here https://corporate.comcast.com/stories/deep-linking-through-a-multiple-activity-stack-on-android

Comment: @DaveKababyan No, this aims single sole Acitivity, replace `FeatureHostingActivity` with your navhost acitivity. By the way that article is even before navigation-component (before Google announce Single Activity Design). I don't think that article is useful enough for navigation-component deep link.

Comment: Let me thank you again for all your help. I tried to implement your suggestion (I don't know how correctly I did it) I have an UPDATE in my initial question with code. When I click on the link, I do get the intent details but it looks like the navController.handleDeepLink(it) line doesn't work. The Linke takes me to the entry point of the application.

Comment: `handleDeepLink` is what Navcontroller do to handle deeplink check [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#handleDeepLink(android.content.Intent)).  Also may be you need to check Intent flags on your manifest, NavController recognizes those. For example (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)

Comment: Thanks! I will check out the docs to see how to fix it. I tried to make your version work, and tested all the Flags as well. The time it was working, it had same issue that I have with my solution. When user opens the app from the deep link, it navigates to Home/Deep link destination of the product. But somehow after that every time the user taps on the home tab at the bottom, it always shows the deepLink product. Its like it always keeps the view on top of the stack even if I click the back button and go to other views.

Comment: @DaveKababyan after deep link, may be you have to `navigateUp` rather than `navigateBack`. After deep link, `navigateUp` behaves differently.

Comment: I am always using NavigateUP when the back button is pressed in my toAppBar.