# How to use firebase deeplink from main activity not only from single screen?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-deep-link

I set up entire deeplink, everything works fine, but sometimes when I am on another screen and close(not kill) application and activate my `firebasedeeplink` it does not goes to my place. I suppose of course it does not trigger this method.

This is my method from `homeScreen`

```
@Composable
fun HandleDeepLinkIfNeeded(
    showSyncDialog: Boolean,
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    val contexts = LocalContext.current

    LaunchedEffect(showSyncDialog) {

        if (!showSyncDialog) {
            val activity = contexts.findActivity()
            val intent = activity?.intent
            Firebase.dynamicLinks
                .getDynamicLink(intent)
                .addOnSuccessHandling(navController) {
                    intent?.replaceExtras(Bundle())
                    intent?.data = null
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The question is how to handle firebase dynamic links globally maybe on `MainActivity`?
If I try use onNewIntent how to get navcontroller there?
I have onCreate method in MainActiviy where I use

```
setContent {
    navController = rememberNavController()
}
```

If I use the same method as`setContent' in 'onNewIntent` my app does not work properly.

How to achieve this effect with dynamic links properly?

I also tried this recommended method, but intent is null I do not know why?

[Deep Link handling in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75853378/deep-link-handling-in-jetpack-compose/76269821#76269821)